# Docker volumes not woking on Fedora28

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to create backup of db on docker (from one container to host). I followed instructions of Docker [website](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes). Even watched videos on youtube how to do it. I did all they did. But still. Not a single file showed up.
I started then with simple creation of simple file. And you guess it... Not a single new file is shown when I list directory content. What I did was:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/dir ubuntu bash -c "echo foo >/dir/file.txt"
```

On video guy making the same had a file. I do not. I think this can be some kind of problem with selinux or fedora itself, but I don't have a clue where can I look for answer anymore.

It is worth mentioning that I am using docker-machine.

Answer (score 0):

This was not so obvious for me. I have used docker-machine to do it. And, though I have run my commands on host they were proxied by docker-machine. And files were created. On the virtual machine.